# Plot3D: Inconsistent distance to PlotLabel when using Grid/Row

Tags: plotting, style, grid-layouts, row

While trying to arrange a grid of 3d-plots using `Plot3D` and `GraphicsGrid` (or simply `Grid`) I noticed that each individual plot is getting resized and a lot of whitespace is being added between the plot body and plot label.  Is there a way to display the 3d-plots next to each other with the label distance remaining the same as it was outside of `Grid`?

I tried to illustrate this with an example below using `Row` though it applies to other commands such as `GraphicsGrid` as well.

Here is my code:

```
{ p1 , p2 } = Plot3D[  # , {x , -5 , 5 } , { y, -5 , 5 } , 
ViewPoint -> {1, 1, .1 }, 
PlotLabel -> #, ImageSize -> Small ] & /@ { x y , x y^2};
Row@{p1,p2}
```

Each of the plots individually has the label touching the plot body
[image]

But when they are together inside a `Row` or `Grid` each plot is apparently resized to a square bounding box (orange) and the label is too far away
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Labeled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Labeled.html) to place the labels and use the option [`PlotRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRegion.html) in `Plot3D`:

```
pr22 = 1.4;

{lp1, lp2} = Labeled[Plot3D[#, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, .1}, 
      SphericalRegion -> True, ImageSize -> Small, 
      PlotRegion -> {{0, 1}, {0, pr22}}], #, Top] & /@ {x y, x y^2};

Row @ {lp1, lp2}
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

In version 13.0.0 (Wolfram Cloud) you can simply use `Labeled`:

```
{lpa, lpb} = Labeled[Plot3D[#, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
   ViewPoint -> {1, 1, .1}, ImageSize -> Small ], #, Top] & /@ {x y, x y^2};

Row @ {lpa, lpb}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked!  Curiously, on my machine (`13.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)`) the `Labeled` version does not work without `PlotRegion`. Also, `SphericalRegion` seems to be unnecessary.  I wonder if there is a way to figure out in advance what the value of `PlotRegion` should be?

Comment: @AndR, I don't know of any automatic way to set `PlotRegion`. For 3D graphics we will need different settings  `PlotRegion` for different viewpoints to get the desired result.